# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

I loop over my array with the .map() function the code works as expected but I got the following TS error:

Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

```
Data of the book.benefitsBlock array = ["old", "roman", "nice", "funny"]
```

```
<Benefits>
    {book.benefitsBlock.map((book) => (
        <Benefit key={book}>{book}</Benefit>
    ))}
</Benefits>
```

Comment: It means that according to TS `book.benefitsBlock` is a string. If you have an *array*, then there is some mixup that was done with the types - TS doesn't examine your runtime data, it only works off the information you've provided at compile time.

Comment: That was the case indeed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the solution to your issue could be to use a type guard to check that you have an array before attempting to use the map method.

so, something like this:

```
  <Benefits>
    {book.benefitsBlock instanceof Array ? (
      book.benefitsBlock.map((book) => <Benefit key={book}>{book}</Benefit>)
    ) : (
      <h1>some other code as book.benefitsBlock is not an Array </h1>
    )}
  </Benefits>
```