# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'. TYPESCRIPT

Tags: string, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript, so this might be a simple error, but here it is:

```ts
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { Container, ButtonSubmit } from './styles';

const Form: React.FC = () => {

  const [movieName, setMovieName] = useState('');
  const [review, setReview] = useState('');
  const [movieReviewList, setMovieReviewList] = useState('');

  useEffect(() =>{
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/get').then((response)=>{
      setMovieReviewList(response.data)
    })
  }, [])

  const submitReview = () => {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/insert', {
      movieName: movieName, movieReview: review
    }).then(() => {
      alert('sucessful insert')
    })
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <label>Movie Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="movieName" placeholder="Write your movie name" onChange={(e) => {
        setMovieName(e.target.value)
      }}/>

      <label>Movie Review</label>
      <input type="text" name="movieReview" placeholder="Write your movie review" onChange={(e) => {
        setReview(e.target.value)
      }}/>

      <ButtonSubmit onClick={submitReview}>Submit</ButtonSubmit>

      {movieReviewList.map((val) => {
        return <h1>MovieName: {val.movieName} | Movie Review: {val.movieReview}</h1>
      })}
      
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

And here is the error:

```
**Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.  TS2339**

    39 |       <ButtonSubmit onClick={submitReview}>Submit</ButtonSubmit>
    40 | 
    41 |       {movieReviewList.map((val) => {
       |                        ^
    42 |         return <h1>MovieName: {val.movieName} | Movie Review: {val.movieReview}</h1>
    43 |       })}
    44 |
```

Comment: `const [movieReviewList, setMovieReviewList] = useState('')` are you sure an empty string is correct here?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66260367/property-map-does-not-exist-on-type-string

Comment: As VLAZ mentioned, you are passing an empty string to `useState`. This means that `movieReviewList` will be inferred as a string. If you want it to be an array, you can pass an empty array as the default value to useState like so: `useState([])`